# pip install django-twilio Error installation

Tags: django, pip, twilio

Trying to install django-twilo using pip on ubuntu machine
Getting error
referring [doc](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

```
workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/home/rahul/workspace/repository/inteliexam_workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached django_twilio-0.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting django-phonenumber-field>=0.6 (from django-twilio)
  Using cached django-phonenumber-field-1.3.0.tar.gz
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/repository/inteliexam_workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/repository/inteliexam_workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import setuptools.version
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/repository/inteliexam_workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/home/rahul/workspace/repository/inteliexam_workspace/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo. It is `django-twilio`, not `django-twillio`

Answer (score 1):

The right command that you should use, as you can see from the [doc](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) is

```
pip install django-twilio
```

and not

```
pip install django-twillio
```

**EDIT**

To fix your problem you can run this command

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

and after run again

```
pip install django-twilio
```

Comment: im using " pip install django-twilio " only still showing error

Comment: try to run "pip install -U setuptools" and rerun the command to install django-twilio

Comment: If this doesn't work, you can try with this command pip install -U pip

Comment: perfect, i'm going to updating my answer in order to help other users with the same issue. Please mark the answer as correct if works for you